# What is the difference between cassandra client side query and cassandra server side query and how it impacts the performance

Tags: cassandra, influxdb

As a part of comparing performance between InfluxDB and cassandra for time series data, InfluxDB is definitely better that cassandra for use case related to time series but I came to know that cassandra query performance varies depending on the queries being handled by server or client. If someone can help me here to understand it better.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "client side" or "server side" queries in a Cassandra context. Can you include some examples about what you are asking about? I think the answer to your question is that there is no such thing as a client side query.

Comment: I am referring to the page number 8 of this document link : http://get.influxdata.com/rs/972-GDU-533/images/InfluxDB%201.4%20vs.%20Cassandra%20.pdf

Comment: I am assuming it means for client side its pulling all the values of the time series to the client, then doing the calculations. Although I doubt anyone else would make this comparison (C* and influxdb are different kinds of databases) marketing literature from company selling something isn't the best place to look for benchmarks.

Comment: I totally understand that. I was just curious to know what exactly it means. Thanks for your time and response.